# Reducing the integer factorization problem to an NP-Complete problem

Tags: np-complete, reductions, factoring

I'm struggling to understand the relationship between NP-Intermediate and NP-Complete. I know that if P != NP based on Ladner's Theorem there exists a class of languages in NP but not in P or in NP-Complete. Every problem in NP can be reduced to an NP-Complete problem, however I haven't seen any examples for reducing a suspected NPI problem (such as integer factorization) into an NP-Complete problem. Does anyone know of any example of this or another NPI->NPC reduction?

Comment: By the definition of NP-completeness, any problem in NP can be reduced to any NP-complete problem. In particular, Cook's theorem shows that SAT is NP-complete, and so gives you "explicitly" such a reduction.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I understand that there is a formalization that such a method exists, however I was looking for a more concrete algorithmic approach similar to, say the reduction of the Hamiltonian Cycle problem to the Traveling Salesman problem. Wherein you can set all the edge weights to 1 and run TSP on the graph and check if the distance traveled is greater than |E|. Something like that I suppose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example, there is a neat classic reduction of factoring to SAT which is also a source of presumed "hard" SAT instances. Basically one uses EE ideas for binary multiplication encoded into the SAT circuit. Think of binary multiplication as an addition of a series of left shifted multiplicands, each "masked" (ANDed) by the bits of a multiplier. The additions can be performed by a binary addition circuit which is a series of full adders.

A talented undergraduate could build this algorithm. I don't know where it was first proposed or implemented in the literature. I would be interested to hear any references.

See e.g. [Satisfy This: An Attempt at Solving Prime Factorization using Satisfiability Solvers by Stefan Schoenmackers and Anna Cavender](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse573/04au/Project/mini1/TheS&Ateam/SATeamFinalPaper.pdf) which lays it out in detail. Also the [DIMACS SAT challenge](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~russell/classes/cs289/f04/readings/Cook+Mitchell:1997.pdf) starting in the late 90s had factoring instances that were generated by some researchers but possibly the algorithm was not written up seperately in a paper during that era.

Comment: fyi the paper link is now 403 forbidden

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph: Cook's theorem shows that any problem in NP can be reduced to SAT.

Comment: right, the Cook proof is a general theoretical existence proof and there are more direct/specialized conversions/algorithms often constructed between NP complete problems (usually with better "overhead"). was referring to the latter.

Answer (score 11):

Just to be absolutely clear, Integer Factorization is not known to be NP-intermediate, just suspected to be based on the lack of either NP-completeness proof or polynomial-time algorithm (despite lots of work put into both). I don't know of any natural problem (i.e. not constructed by Ladner for the proof) that is definitely NP-intermediate if P and NP are different.

Okay, after that disclaimer, [Graph Isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) is another likely candidate for a natural NP-intermediate problem. There's a simple polynomial-time reduction from it to [Subgraph Isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) - just leave the graphs the same! Graph Isomorphism is just the special case of Subgraph Isomorphism where both graphs have the same size. The final touch is that Subgraph Isomorphism *is* NP-complete.

Apart from that, there is always of course the not-so-informative reduction promised by the  [Cook-Levin Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem), we known that any NP-intermediate problem has some nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing Machine that decides it, and we can convert this into an instance of SAT (just have to build the TM!).